# using DPDK-basicfwd example how to send custom packet to desired port

Tags: dpdk

Requirement: I would like to make use of DPDK basicfwd, to send back custom reply to the incoming port.

Explanation:

DPDK ports: Port-0 and Port-1
Sample code: edited DPDK basicfwd.
Custom Function: `PacketHandler()`
Requirement: Sometimes I need to send custom packet(kind of RST packet) to incoming port.

example: `Port-0 -> RX burst -> PacketHandler() -> normal packets fwd to Port-1, special packets send back to Port-0`

Code Snippet:

```
while (isRun) {
    num_rx = rte_eth_rx_burst(port_id, queue_id, mbufs, BURST_SIZE);
    if (num_rx == 0) {
        continue;
    }

    num_tx = 0;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < num_rx; idx++) {
        struct pcap_pkthdr pktHdr;
        gettimeofday(&pktHdr.ts, NULL);
        pktHdr.caplen = rte_pktmbuf_pkt_len(mbufs[idx]);
        pktHdr.len = rte_pktmbuf_pkt_len(mbufs[idx]);

        if (PacketHandler(&pktHdr, rte_pktmbuf_mtod(mbufs[idx], unsigned char *)) > 1) {
            printf("Blocked Packets, do not fwd");
            //TODO: send custom packet to incoming way
            rte_pktmbuf_free(mbufs[idx]);
            continue;
        }

        txbufs[num_tx++] = mbufs[idx];            
    }

    if (num_tx > 0) {
        sent = rte_eth_tx_burst(port_id ^ 1, queue_id, txbufs, num_tx);
        for (int idx = sent; idx < num_tx; idx++) {
            rte_pktmbuf_free(txbufs[idx]);
        }
    }
}
```

My custom packet type is u_char. How can i send my packet to incoming way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option `1`: Simple way (but can affect performance)

1. get packets via `rte_eth_rx_burst`
2. iterate packets, to update dest_port = PacketHandler() ? mbufs[idx]->port : (mbufs[idx]->port ^ 1)
3. Send packet out with `rte_eth_tx_burst` with `dest_port`
4. Comment out the tx_burst generic call below.

Option `2`:

1. Create 2 mbuf-array namely mbufs_inport, and mbufs_outport.
2. Iterate packets, to invoke PacketHandler(). Matching Packets goes to `mbufs_inport` and non-matching goes to `mbufs_outport`
3. to invoke `rte_eth_tx_burst` for `mbufs_inport` and `mbufs_outprt`.

Option `3`:

1. register rx-callback to filter packets with `packethandler`.
2. Now you have the option to directly send back the selected back based on `mbuf->portid`. While non-matching packets continue in the main loop.
3. If there is concern about `packet order` or `previous packets needs to be processed`, make use of `mbuf-udata64` as a place holder for exit port. For cases not matching set is as `-1`. Then in the main loop, you have convert tx_burst for `n` packets to iterate for each as you have to check for `udata64` value.

Comment: this is with the assumption PacketHandler modifies the content to desired RST format and does not change the packet_len. If the packet length is altered, please update mbuf->data_len and mbuf->pktlen too.

Comment: thanks for answer. my custom packet will be change packet_len. For me, this special case will be run less than 0.1%. so performance is ok. I'm trying to follow option1. I think, it is change packet and push into txbufs, instead of delete origin packet. is it correct?

Comment: when i get packet from mbuf, i use `rte_pktmbuf_mtod`, how can i insert my packet to mbuf?

Comment: you have to memcpy the content and update mbuf->pkt_len or mbuf->data_len if you are modifying the packet.

Comment: Thanks, In addition, if i try to send new my packet, not modifying. how can I send it? should I fill member of mbuf by myself or have some other rte_function?

Comment: if there is no modification, using same tx_burst API